# Is it a bad idea to take drugs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim there are a few drugs and alcoholic beverages and I couldn't really figure out whether or not there are big disadvantages.
I always rely on my own potions because I'm not sure about the side effects of those things.

Can you get addicted by certain drugs (let's say Skooma) or can the game be unplayable due to a blurry screen? Or does it even reduce skill levels and/or other important things at some points? What are the advantages/disadvantages of drinking alcohol and taking drugs in Skyrim?

Comment: To the hot network questions with you! Go, out of context title, join your brothers!

Comment: @PeterL I totally thought it was related to the [manager smoking crack at work](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19761/should-i-tell-my-co-workers-that-branch-manager-uses-drugs-crack-at-the-office) question from just seeing the title... :D

Comment: Although doing so would render the comment from @PeterL invalid and thus destroy the humour, I'm strongly inclined to change the title of this question to give it context.

Comment: keep in mind the tags add context as well, even to the page title.

Comment: I like a good laugh as much as anyone, but these sorts of questions always serve to highlight how meaningless upvotes/downvotes actually are in practice on sites like this.

Comment: 33 upvotes just because of the title.

Comment: Yes! I knew this was from Arqade the moment I saw the title. No more will you torment me, you weird-sounding-out-of-context titles!  *evil laugh*

Comment: I almost never understand what arcade and rpg  questions are about from the title.

Comment: For me the Site icons next to the question title ruins it

Comment: Drugs are bad, mkay.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Every drug-like potion, alcoholic food item, etc. will describe it's behaviour fully in the effects list in your inventory; there is no addiction mechanism, and there are no penalties beyond what is listed (usually just a penalty to stamina regeneration). In fact, [Skooma](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skooma), described in-universe as highly addictive, doesn't even have that!

Comment: always thought it weird they have an addiction system in Fallout yet not in TES games. They being Bethesda

Comment: @Paralytic Addiction in Fallout predates Bethesda taking the series over. And also, Fallout is very much a bleaker, greyer, grittier series, where things like addiction mechanics fit; not so much with TES.

Comment: Skooma, not even once.

Comment: Someone should build an addiction mod for this

Comment: @Cole9350 There already is a Skooma addiction mod: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9315/?

Comment: @Cole9350, Here's another one or two: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/34902
http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/33444

Comment: There's *always* a mod.